# Can I access keyboard history without a keylogger?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, disk-encryption, pgp

By accident I wrongly typed a password (twice) that I completely forgot, when I was encrypting my external Toshiba drive with PGP Disk. I have no backup, nor *.krp files to repair my key, but I am trying now to recover with EaseUS.

Is there any way of seeing what was typed on the laptop`s keyboard on that particular day, without having an active keylogger?

Dell Inspiron 1525

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote, because there were probably a lot of warnings in big, bold letters that the key is irretrievable and that you should make a backup of the keyfile on an external disk. But I have sympathy... you might want to meditate and try your best to remember exactly what you typed. Maybe you had caps lock on by accident?

Comment: Do you have a wife, girlfriend / partner?  Mine is a mind-reader on things like this.  My point is you need lateral thinking on remembering that password.

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer, no, there isn't, otherwise hacking would be a much larger problem than it already is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if there is some sort of factory installed, always running keystroke logger built into Windows that anyone can consult? No.

Answer (score 0):

There definitely isn't a mechanism that keeps history of keystrokes.

Once I had some similar problems, and then decided to install a keylogger on my own private personal computer. That saved me from making mistakes for a while. But after a time period, I uninstalled it because of some security concerns.